# Keyword as argument, is that well-defined?

Tags: powershell

The following Powershell code works OK in my Windows 7 (running in ISE):

```
function is_odd { $args[0] % 2 -eq 1; }
function choose_if { if( $args[0] ) { &$args[1]; } else { &$args[3]; } }

clear-host;
$i = 42;
for( ;; ) {
    write $i
    if( $i -eq 1 ) { break; }
    $i = choose_if( is_odd $i ) { 3*$i + 1 } else { $i/2 };
}
```

But, is it well defined, so that it will continue to work e.g. in Windows 10?

I can't find anything like formal spec of the language.

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that I can just use an ordinary `if`, no need for the `choose_if`. But I learned that by way of going via the `choose_if`. Just now. :)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389 - sadly only goes up to PS v3.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is typically backwards-compatible, and there have been very few breaking changes in the language since version 2.

[Windows PowerShell 5.0 is backward-compatible. Cmdlets, providers, modules, snap-ins, scripts, functions, and profiles that were designed for Windows PowerShell 4.0, Windows PowerShell 3.0, and Windows PowerShell 2.0 generally work in Windows PowerShell 5.0 without changes.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/Hh857339.aspx)

I would be confident that your script would work fine on any powershell version 2.0 or greater.